# function return without any value

Tags: sql, function, oracle10g

I have a sql query in a function

```
SELECT  DISTINCT (product_id)
      INTO  prod
      FROM  products
     WHERE       mfg_no = 'TEL'             
                AND status = p_status
```

Sometimes product_id will be null or p_status will have no data. Because of this function doesn't return any value.

I tried nvl,decode and case statement to check product_id, but none didn't work.
How can I make sure that my function executes fine even if product_id is null or empty?

I have tried to return a value in EXCEPTION block like the following, that didn't help either.

```
EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
    THEN
        prod := 'NA';
```

*Edit 1*

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_function (p_status VARCHAR2)
    RETURN VARCHAR2
AS
    prod     VARCHAR2 (2000);
BEGIN
    prod := NULL;  


    SELECT  DISTINCT (product_id)
      INTO  prod
      FROM  products
     WHERE  mfg_no = 'TEL' AND status = p_status;

    RETURN prod;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
    THEN
        prod := 'N/A';
        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('no data found ' || SQLERRM);
    WHEN OTHERS
    THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('error ' || SQLERRM);
        prod := 'N/A';
END;
```

Comment: Can you show the full code ? where is the `return prod;` line ?

Comment: @A.B.Cade I have added my function in my question as Edit 1. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_function (p_status VARCHAR2)
    RETURN VARCHAR2
AS
    prod     VARCHAR2 (2000);
BEGIN
    prod := NULL;

  BEGIN
    SELECT  DISTINCT (product_id)
      INTO  prod
      FROM  products
     WHERE  mfg_no = 'TEL' AND status = p_status;

  EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
    THEN
        prod := 'N/A';
        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('no data found ' || SQLERRM);
    WHEN OTHERS
    THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('error ' || SQLERRM);
        prod := 'N/A';
  END;

  RETURN prod;

END;
```

---

To see the difference between *no records* and *null value* see [this sqlfiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/09e8c/2)

Comment: Thanks a lot, this really helped. I have a question, what is the best way to handle product_id if it is null? is it better to catch in exception block?

Comment: There is a difference between `null` and `no_data_found` you can use `nvl` when there is a record with `null` value and you catch an exception when there is no records. See the Demo I added

Comment: Great +one. Thanks again, appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution, using NVL / MAX instead of DISTINCT / Exception handling:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_function (p_status VARCHAR2)
    RETURN VARCHAR2
AS
    prod     VARCHAR2 (2000);
BEGIN
    SELECT  NVL(MAX(product_id), 'N/A')
      INTO  prod
      FROM  products
     WHERE  mfg_no = 'TEL' AND status = p_status;
  RETURN prod;

END;
```